# Most efficient way to delimit key

Tags: php, string

Say I have a string of 16 numeric characters (i.e. 0123456789012345) what is the most efficient way to delimit it into sets like : 0123-4567-8901-2345, in PHP?

Note: I am rewriting an existing system that is painfully slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [str_split()](http://php.net/str_split):

```
$string = '0123456789012345';
$sets = str_split($string, 4);
print_r($sets);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0123
    [1] => 4567
    [2] => 8901
    [3] => 2345
)
```

Then of course to insert hyphens between the sets you just [implode()](http://php.net/implode) them together:

```
echo implode('-', $sets); // echoes '0123-4567-8901-2345'
```

Comment: Assuming the OP wants the hyphens inserted, you'd probably then want to do implode( '-', $sets ).

Comment: Yeah, edited that in while you were commenting. At first I assumed he knew the implode() function.

Comment: I do, I know how to do this also, I was A) hoping for something different I didn't already know about, b) putting it out there for other persons, since I've been asked about this 3 times today.

Comment: What's the data source?  If it's a DB, you can have the DB format it for you before it even gets to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more flexible approach (for e.g. phone numbers), try regular expressions:

```
preg_replace('/^(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/', '\1-\2-\3-\4', '0123456789012345');
```

If you can't see, the first argument accepts four groups of four digits each.  The second argument formats them, and the third argument is your input.

Comment: I'm not sure if this wouldn't work better? preg_replace('/(\d{4})/', '-\1', '0123456789012345');

Comment: That wouldn't work, since you'd be left with a '-' hanging in the front of the output.  It also kills some of the flexibility.  I have edited my post to use the {4} syntax, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more general:

```
<?php

// arr[string] = strChunk(string, length [, length [...]] );
function strChunk() {
    $n = func_num_args();
    $str = func_get_arg(0);
    $ret = array();

    if ($n >= 2) {
        for($i=1, $offs=0; $i<$n; ++$i) {
            $chars = abs( func_get_arg($i) );
            $ret[] = substr($str, $offs, $chars);
            $offs += $chars;
        }
    }

    return $ret;
}

echo join('-', strChunk('0123456789012345', 4, 4, 4, 4) );

?>
```